# Gyroscope and gravity in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in unity, and i want to control the gravity in my game with gyroscope on an android i search for a while but couldn't find anything.
Can anyone please help me.
For example if i turn my phone upside down the gravity would also turn upside down.
I have tried
http://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.4/Documentation/en/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-gravity.html
I am only able to find rotation of object.

Comment: Have you checked how to roll a ball with the gyroscope? https://answers.unity.com/questions/976817/roll-a-ball-how-do-i-control-the-ball-with-the-gyr.html I think that should be your first step on this